# Born to British parents

Tags: phrase-usage

Here is a conversation from this movie [Venom 2019](https://transcripts.fandom.com/wiki/Venom):

> What do you say, Mr. Drake, we just start at the beginning? - **Born to British parents.** - Mmm-hmm. And then at 19, you discovered a gene therapy that literally doubles the life expectancy -of pancreatic cancer patients. - Well, actually, it tripled their life expectancy. But it's okay.

Is this sentence common in American and /or British English?

> Born to British parents

Are there any other ways to express that idea?

I can't find any similar phrase and born to [means something else!](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-born-to-do-be-something)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In context, someone is reciting facts they know about Mr. Drake’s history. “Born to British parents” has an implied “you were” - “You were born to British parents.”

It would be simpler to have said “Your parents were British.”, but if this person was reading a file on Mr. Drake at the same time he was speaking, it would make sense for the character to just read a few snippets from the file aloud or summarize what they were reading quickly instead of forming complete thoughtful sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a common phrase.

To say one is "born to" or "born of" someone is to that that they are their parent.